# Internal oscillator drift and its effect on UART

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, clock

I am eager to know whether a 150kHz drift of internal oscilator clock (mentioned in a STM32 MCU operating with 8MHz internal clock) could destroy a UART connection?

Comment: Compare that percentage frequency shift with the percentage tolerance given in the UART datasheet.

Comment: I used an STM32L4 and it did not reliably communicate via UART at 115200 baud when using the 8 MHz MSI internal oscillator.  The clock varied too much from part to part and especially over temperature.  I changed to the HSE clock source with a more precise external crystal to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UART is very robust when it comes to clock accuracy requirements. This is a consequence of the fact that each byte is processed independently and any time difference associated to clock mismatch doesn't propagate for more than 10 bits (start bit + 8 data bits + stop bit) in time.

[This analysis from Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/2141.html) concludes that 2% in clock frequency mismatch is still tolerable. In your particular case you have 150kHz/8MHz, what is equivalent to 1.88%. If the other side of the link has a much more accurate clock (let's say a crystal oscillator with 50ppm, or 0.005%), then the clock mismatch is below 2% and  you should be OK. If both sides of the link have a clock that is 1.88% inaccurate, then in the worst case scenario (one side has 8MHz+150kHz, the other has 8MHz-150kHz) you may have 3.8% of clock difference, in which case you run the risk of starting to see problems.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the UART stands for "asynchronous". You have somwhere in the datasheet a ratio baudrate vs sampling clock, so it is oversampled, then filtered (decimated). The asynchronous clock is reset once the start bit is detected, so there is plenty room for clock inequalities.

For the standard oversampling ratio of 16 , the clocks can be off by +/-5.11% ([Source](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ab22/4152d147075e59f3ba89bc5f374a779b24fe.pdf))

For your case :
$$E=\pm 0.05=\dfrac{X}{8M}$$
$$X=\pm 400kHz$$

Supposing that two similar devices communicate over UART, then each device can deviate maximally for +/-200kHZ, which is within tolerance band of proposed MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you have a crystal-controlled UART at the other end, you are reasonably safe with as much as +/-5% error.

However that error should include initial oscillator error, drift error (temperature, Vcc, time etc.) **and** any error in divider digital ratio.